# Django - Get URL from DB and use it as src in in iframe

Tags: python, django

I have simple requirement. There is a URL that is stored in DB. I need to retrieve this URL from the DB and in my template use this URL as SRC value in an iframe.

*Model.py:*

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class DashboardLink(models.Model):
    dashboard_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

*Views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import DashboardLink

def index(request):
    dashboard_url = DashboardLink.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

**In Index.html I have the following code, in which I want to use the url retrieved from the DB.**

*index.html*

```
    <p>{{ dashboard_url.dashboard_url }}</p>   ### This is to just check if the data is being fetched or not.. This too results in blank. ####


    <section>
        <iframe width="100%" height="700" src="{% for item in dashboard_url %} {{ item }} {% endfor %}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </section>
    <br><br>
</div>
```

```
In urls.py I have the following code:

*urls.py*
```

path('index/', logged_in_views.index, name='index'),

```
When I use Inspect, I see the following
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Can someone please help me in understanding what am I missing?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Oek.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send context to template:

```
def index(request):
    dashboard_url = DashboardLink.objects.all()
    context = { "dashboard_url": dashboard_url}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

You can use `models.URLField` for urls too

Comment: Now I get the following:    src=" DashboardLink object (1) "    In the command line I see the following error :     Not Found: /index/DashboardLink object (1)

Comment: You must change `{{ item }}` to `{{ item.dashboard_url }}`